# Can´t delete disks through gcloud google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, disk

I'm trying to delete a disk through gcloud but it does not work :/.
Every other command works (create, attach, detach).

This is the code im using:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=KEY
gcloud compute disks delete disk_name --zone=europe-west3-b
```

When i execute the code nothing happens. If i press "stop operation" it will stay on that status forever and i have to restart Powershell. The Service-Account has compute instance administrator rights (v1) so it can`t be that.

Updated to the newest version but it didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1. Please update your question with version of Cloud SDK `gcloud vesion` (current version is 281.0.0). Try to upgrade it and run your commands again. 2. Did you try to run this commands in `Cloud Shell` that you could activate via UI? 3. Try run `gcloud compute disks list | grep disk_name`. 4. Which role does your service account use `Compute Instance Admin (v1) role` or `Compute Instance Admin (beta) role`?

Comment: I tried deleting the disk with a cloud sdk shell and it works. Maybe the Powershell ISE can't return prompts from gcloud. Because before i never got asked anything and it just froze.

Comment: Yes that was the reason. I just added -q to the command so that there is no prompt. Thanks for you input :).

Comment: Send an answer and i'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem related to `Powershell ISE` that can't return prompts from `gcloud`. It could be solved by following the documentation [Scripting gcloud CLI commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud):

> Cloud SDK comes with a variety of tools like filtering, formatting,
>   and the **--quiet flag**, enabling you to effectively handle output and
>   automate tasks.

and using flag `-q`.